# android-Can't change no of stars in rating bar in alert dialog

Tags: android

I've used an alert dialog to get a star rating bar in it.But i can't change the number of stars being displayed(now it displays 6..i want it to be 5)..

There is no corresponding XML for the rating bar because it is dynamically made.
Ive tried the setNumStars() method but no use....also tried changing to wrapcontent.

here is my code..please help

```
enter code here

protected void showRatingAlert() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         AlertDialog.Builder ab =  new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.this);
         ab.setTitle("Enter Rating");ab.setMessage("STARS"); 
         final RatingBar rat =  new RatingBar(AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.this);
         rat.setNumStars(5);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         rat.setLayoutParams(lp);
         ab.setView(rat);
         ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 float val = rat.getRating();

 if(ur.equals("0"))
 {
    nr = val;
 }
else
{
    nr = (art+val)/2;

}
```

Comment: Have your tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

From `RatingBar` docs:

> Sets the number of stars to show. In order for these to be shown properly, it is recommended the layout width of this widget be wrap content.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setNumStars(int)

So in your case you can create layout, for instance `layout/rating.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:numStars="5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And use this layout as dialog context. Here is modified dialog's code:

```
protected void showRatingAlert() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AlertDialog.Builder ab =  new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.this);
    ab.setTitle("Enter Rating");ab.setMessage("STARS"); 

    //inflating layout and finding RatingBar widget
    View root = ((LayoutInflater) AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.rating, null);
    ab.setView(root);

    final RatingBar rat = (RatingBar)root.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);


    rat.setNumStars(5);


    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    //and all your existing code
    ...
```